# How do we get output layer in skip-gram?

Tags: neural-network, nlp, word-embeddings, word2vec

Could you please explain how do we get output layer in this architecture (vectors `[0.2, 0.8, -1.4, 1.2]` and `[-0.3, 0.2, -0.7, 0.1]`). I understand that layer before are embeddings of word "brown". But how do we get vector `[0.2, 0.8, -1.4, 1.2]`? I thought it should be dot product of "brown"'s embeddings with "quick"'s embeddings? Could you please describe in details how this part works?

[image]

Comment: I'd start by reading this: https://towardsdatascience.com/the-simple-approach-to-word-embedding-for-natural-language-processing-using-python-ae028c8dbfd2

Comment: The vectors have been learned from predicting related and unrelated word pairs: http://mccormickml.com/2016/04/19/word2vec-tutorial-the-skip-gram-model/

Answer (score 0):

We have 2 embedding matrices(U,V) that are `learnt during word2vec training`.
U has shape (vocab_size, dimensions)
V has shape (dimension, vocab_size)
For any given pair of target, context:

1. We pick embedding of target from U(one of the rows in U matrix) and calculate it"s dot product with all the vectors in V matrix leading to a score vector(third from last vector). score_vector has dimension vocab_size*1

This score vector(output vector in question) is taken into probability space by using softmax operation.
Now we have predicted probabilities ie softmax(score_vector) and actual probability vector ie one-hot vector of context word.

In other words we want probability distribution that predicts context word(here `quick`) with higher probability than the rest of the words.

Once we have predicted vector and actual vector we calculate loss(ie. cross entropy) and backpropogate it to modify both U and V.